# prime powers modulo prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I stumbled upon the following property: $n\equiv n^5\bmod 5$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, so out of I tried other (prime) numbers $n\equiv n^p\bmod p$.

My question is whether this is true for all primes $p$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and if so, how to prove it. Also, are there any non-primes for which the relation holds?

It might be a very basic fact I've forgotten.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html  and http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat's_Little_Theorem

Comment: Have a look at [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem). It states that for any prime $p$ and an integer $a$, we have $a^p \equiv a\; (\textrm{mod}\; p)$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I knew it was something I had heard of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). Its generalization is [Fermat-Euler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

*"Also, are there any non-primes for which the relation holds?"*

Yes.

It is called **Euler's Theorem**, and is basically a generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem.

It states the following:

Let $\gcd(a,n)=1$

Then $$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

**Proof**:

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots a_{\phi(n)}$ be the [reduced canonical residues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system%E2%80%8E) modulo $n$. As $(a,n)=1$ $aa_1,aa_2,\dots,aa_{\phi(n)}$ are also a complete set of incongruent reduced residues.

Thus,

$$aa_1\cdot aa_2\cdots aa_{\phi(n)} \equiv a_1a_2\cdots a_{\phi(n)} \pmod{n}$$

$$a^{\phi(n)}a_1a_2\cdots a_{\phi(n)}\equiv a_1a_2\cdots a_{\phi(n)}$$

Since, $\gcd(a_1a_2\cdots a_{\phi(n)},n)=1$ we may cancel it out of both sides,

$$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

---

If $n$ is prime, then $\phi(n)=n-1$ and if $\gcd(a,n)=1$. Then we have,

$$a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{n} \iff a^n\equiv a\pmod{n}$$

On the other hand, if $\gcd(a,n)\ne1$, then $n|a$ since $n$ is prime, and both sides are congruent to $0$ modulo $n$.

Thus Fermat's little theorem is a special case of Euler's Theorem.

---

**Note:** $\phi(n)$ denotes [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient_function).